# bltoolkit inserting data to a table

Tags: c#, persistence, entity, bltoolkit

I have this entity :

```
namespace Entities.dbo
{
    [TableName("tbl_snapshot")]
    public class Snapshot : AbstractEntity
    {
        [MapField("track")]
        public int TrackId { get; set; }

        [Association(CanBeNull = false, OtherKey = "id", ThisKey = "track")]
        public Track Track { get; set; }

        [MapField("snapshotnumber")]
        public int SnapshotNumber { get; set; }

        [MapField("data")]
        public string Data { get; set; }
}}
```

and I try to insert a new Snapshot into a database like this :

```
public static void XXX(Snapshot snapshot)
        {
            using (var db = new MyDbManager())
            {

                var s = new Snapshot
                                 {
                                     Id = snapshot.Id,
                                     Data = snapshot.Data,
                                     SnapshotNumber = snapshot.SnapshotNumber,
                                     TrackId = snapshot.Track.Id
                                 };


                db.GetTable<Snapshot>().Insert(() => s);
            }
        }
```

Can you see any problem there? the snapshot I send to the XXX method look like this:

(Serialized in JSON ):

```
{"TrackId":2,"Track":null,"SnapshotNumber":2,"Data":"030405","Id":3}
```

any idea where is the problem?

thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an exception? Is the data incorrect? ...

Comment: no exception, the insert is not proceeded, nothing is inserted

Comment: oh, so i catch the exception finally and it says : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Comment: Need full call stack on an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Bltoolkit's LinQ insert method does not support a constant value:
    db.GetTable().Insert(() => s);
s is a constant value.

Here are 02 solutions you can try:

1. Simply don't use the LinQ method:

   db.Insert(s);
2. If you still want LinQ method? please follows this link, you will find a workaround:

http://yfilonov.blogspot.com/2012/10/linq-warkaround-for-bltoolkit-insert.html